# Why does installing Debian from DVD download many packages?

Tags: debian, install, desktop, dvd

I know Debian is general purpose, so a Debian install could just as easily be a server as a desktop. It seems, however, that even with a DVD of disk1 from Debian, it is downloading a tremendous number of files from the network mirror. I would have thought a DVD would be enough to get a base desktop installation running. What am I missing here?

Let me clarify: I chose "SSH Server" and "Desktop Environment" in tasksel. Is GNOME not a part of the primary installation DVD?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

What package sets or packages did you ask for?

Perhaps it's just downloading updates rather than packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the full debian distribution for even a single architecture now well exceeds seven DVDs, and the packages on each DVD are sorted by popularity, not by common theme.

Every single installation manual strongly recommends installing from a minimal CD or USB image (100 MB or less, generally) and installing over the internet, or a local apt proxy if you have multiple systems to set up.

In addition to that, the DVDs do not contain the latest versions of all packages -- security updates aren't automatically integrated into the DVD images until the next point release. Regenerating the entire image set (Remember there's roughly seven DVDs per architecture for a dozen or so actively supported architectures and you'll see why the development team prefers not to do live rebuilds every single time a package is updated.)

Answer (score 1):

You would get better response if

- you didn't use such a vague and inflammatory title (I've fixed that for you);
- you gave a list of packages you chose to install, and a list of packages that were not on the DVD.

Your question being what it is, here are two guesses:

- The packages downloaded from the network are security or other updates, issued after the DVD image was built.
- You have unusual tastes.

As [mentioned in the Debian CD FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#which-cd), packages are sorted into Debian CDs and DVDs mainly according to their [popularity](http://popcon.debian.org/).

Comment: I don't see what was so inflammatory about the initial title.